# How to change Accessibility focus in iOS when a new View controller is presented on top of it?

Tags: ios, swift, accessibility, presentmodalviewcontroller

I have 2 view controllers. First VC has a table View and there are switches inside each cell. On pressing these buttons, I will move to the Second VC. Now the issue here is, when I do the accessibilty testing, it starts reading stuffs on First VC, but when I press the button to move to Second VC, it keeps reading the elements and labels from First VC instead of changing focus to the Second VC.

I have tried using

```
UIAccessibility.post(notification: .screenChanged, argument: self.myFirstView)
```

and  `view.accessibilityViewIsModal = true`
but still no effect. A quick short example would help as to how the accessibility flow works and how to resolve this issue.